# C++ UDP recvfrom is acting strange, WSAGetLastError = 10014

Tags: c++, udp

My code is behaving very strange on Windows, but working on Linux...
This is my server.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "packet.h"
#include "socket.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Socket s;

s.bindAt(1337);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Packet p;
    int32_t a;
    char *b;

    int abc = s.receive();
    printf("abc = %d\n", abc);
    printf("error = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    p.getInt(&a);
    p.getString(&b);

    printf("int = %d\nstring = %s\n", a, b);
    delete[] b;
}

return 0;
}
```

and here is the socket.cpp:

```
Socket::Socket()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
WSADATA wsa;
if (sockNum == 0 && WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    throw 1;
#endif

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
#ifdef _WIN32
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
#else
if (sock == -1)
#endif
    throw 2;

addrlen = 0;
sockNum++;
}


int Socket::bindAt(unsigned short port)
{
struct sockaddr_in sa = { 0 };
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(port);
sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
return bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa));
}

ssize_t Socket::receive()
{
ssize_t n;

#ifdef _WIN32

char msg[100];
n = recvfrom(sock,msg, sizeof(msg), 0,(SOCKADDR*) &addr, &addrlen);
#else
n = recvfrom(sock, p->buf, p->bufSize, 0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &addr, &addrlen);
#endif
/*if (n < 0)
    p->bufSize = 0;
else
    p->bufSize = n;*/
return n;
}
```

and basically the header of it:

```
typedef SOCKET socket_t;
typedef int ssize_t;

class Socket
{
public:
socket_t sock;
socklen_t addrlen;
struct sockaddr_in addr;

Socket();
~Socket();

int connect(const char *ip, unsigned short port);
int bindAt(unsigned short port);
ssize_t send(Packet *p);
ssize_t receive();
};
```

If I change the last 2 parameters of the recvfrom, the (SOCKADDR*) &addr, and &addrlen to NULL it works, but what is wrong with these 2 parameters?

Comment: Did you try initializing addrlen with sizeof(addr)?

Comment: addrlen = sizeof(addr); Wut this works!, how???

Comment: @dtb Look earlier in the MSDN. Under `SOCK_DGRAM` it says _This socket type uses the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) for the Internet address family (AF_INET or AF_INET6)._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of this :

```
addrlen = 0;
```

do this:

```
addrlen = sizeof(sockaddr_in)
```

it should work, because you are identifying correctly the size of the output address buffer pointer.

Comment: The last parameter of `recvfrom()` is an **in/out** parameter, which is why it is passed by pointer. On input, it specifies the **total size of the buffer**. On output, it returns the **amount of buffer space actually used**. It is not a good idea to use a class member for that value, unless you re-initialize the value every time `recvfrom()` is called. Initializing it only in the constructor is not good enough.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Isn't that reinitialization necessary whether it's a class member or an ordinary variable?

Comment: @Barmar: It is necessary every time `recvfrom()` is called. That is why I said initializing it only in the constructor is not enough. The first time `recvfrom()` is called, the variable will get updated, and may have the wrong value for the next call to `recvfrom()` if it is not re-initialized.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't questioning whether it's necessary to reinitialize it every time, I was questioning your statement that it's not a good idea to use a class member for it. If `addr` is a class member, `addrlen` should also be, so that you can keep the two together.

Comment: @Barmar: Personally, I would change the `addr` member to a `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` and not worry about keeping track of the `addrlen` at all. `Socket::Receive()` could then use a local variable for `addrlen` when calling `recvfrom()`.

Comment: all in all, what size will be returned ? The size of sockaddr_in, because the user is using IPV4.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description of `WSAEFAULT` (10014):

> The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument of a call. This error occurs if an application passes an invalid pointer value, or if the **length of the buffer is too small**. For instance, if the length of an argument, which is a sockaddr structure, is smaller than the sizeof(sockaddr).

So if you supply an uninitialized value of `addrlen`, it may be too small, and result in this error.

If `addr` is `NULL`, it means you don't want the address filled in, so `addrlen` is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info btw (little late :P)